# Facebooks API. What should i choose ? (walltext inside)

Tags: facebook, api

I'm a little bit lost.
So, I'm not really trying to integrate facebook with my webproject, but in some point I need to get some information of a fb account... like friend's email, name, status and some other things...

From what I read so far, it seems that it's no longer possible to get friends' email and some other information without the friends authorize you app to do that, at least when using the last api from fb (graph api)... so I thought that was something impossible to do, until I see some sites (like yahoo) offering a possibility to import your contacts from your fb account without his friends authorize. Does anyone know how they do that?

I tried using other apis, like facebook-java-api, restFB, and others but in all cases I'm getting some kind of error... so if someone could at least give me a direction or something like that... have you done this? or know how to? using which api?
some info: I'm developing in Java with Eclipse, using tomcat as my web server.
well it's a little bit confusing since its not a technical issue, but if someone could help me pointing some direction I could tell each error i got when trying to go this direction or something like that.

Comment: the facebook API stays the same - there is the depricated REST API and the newer graph API.  You should use the graph API - but what you are talking about is different SDK's..not API's

Answer (score 0):

You dont HAVE to use an SDK at all... Basically the only URL you need to be aware of is `graph.facebook.com` and you can just make HTTP requests to that URL.  You might want to look into the facebook connect feature too.

Comment: first tnx for the reply...
well thats the problem, with graph api i cannot take the friends email and others information since this friend have not authorized my app. so how can i get this informations ?i thought that some sdk's were able to let me do that...

Comment: no - facebook privacy policies require you to explicitly request permissions to access that data.  SDK's cant bypass facebooks authentication.

Comment: dammit thats confusing...
have you seen yahoo's tool(just one example) that imports your's fb friends? how they manage to do that ?

Comment: you have to authenticate the yahoo tool so that it can query your friend list.  There is no other way to do it.  There is a specific permission for facebook apps to retrieve your friend list.

Comment: yeah i've seen that you have to accept the app permissions in your fb account, but in my app for example, i had checked all permissions... and still i cant get my friends email... aways null... =/

Comment: ahh i missed that - you CAN CERTAINLY NOT retrieve friends emails from facebook.  SPAM WARNING!

Comment: lol ! are you calm ?
this is what i've been asking all the time... if i cant retrive the email, how does yahoo do it ?

Comment: They could store only the users FBID in their database and have it referencing their yahoo email that they already have.  All they are doing is seeing if any of your friends are known to them - if so - voila - that friend has a yahoo account.   It would be a VERY bad idea to let people retrieve users emails without their EXPLICIT permissions.  Yea sorry for the CAPS :P

Comment: hmm.... tnx for the answer...i just thought that could be a way to get this data information since  i saw the yahoo's tools working and when i acess any of my friends page and go to information im able to see his email... well tnx for the information and sorry about the stupid questions... dont worry about the caps, its there for a purpose... lol